# SQL Server - unused LEFT JOIN impacts execution plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, query-performance

I have a query like this

```
SELECT TableA.Id FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.Id = TableB.TableAId
```

In this case columns from table B are actually not used and could not affect the result because it's not an INNER JOIN. But the execution plan clearly shows that it's being used and it affects the performance. Shouldn't SQL Server optimize it to eliminate unused operations? Is there a way to set some execution hints to do that or rewrite the query to only use this join when it's actually present in SELECT or WHERE clause?

Unfortunately, I can't just remove the unused join from query. In real life it's a more complex view that joins many tables and it's always used with different SELECT list or WHERE condition

Comment: Is the TableAId column unique?  (Otherwise the LEFT JOIN may generate multiple rows.)

Comment: @jarlh yes, it's unique

Comment: @jarlh actually, you're right, it's because of uniqueness. TableB is a view that has UNION statement and apparently it prevents SQL Server from deducing it's uniqueness. thanks!

Comment: "columns from table B are actually not used" What? "= TableB.TableAId" Re "could not affect the result because it's not an INNER JOIN" Left join returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Your introduction doesn't make sense. Please give a [mre] & refer to it to explain what you are trying to say. That includes constraints, in case you are relying on a special case--they are for integrity & optimization. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS What has your research shown?--including the manual & googling with site:stackoverflow.com. [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A LEFT JOIN can alter the result even if their columns are not in the result set.

See how these two querys return different results :

```
create table TableA (TableAId int)
create table TableB (TableBId int, TableAId int)

insert into TableA (TableAId) values (100), (200), (300)
insert into TableB (TableBId, TableAId) values (1, 100), (1, 200), (2, 100), (3, 300)

select TableA.TableAId 
from TableA

select TableA.TableAId 
from TableA
     left join TableB on TableB.TableAId = TableA.TableAId
```

That's because if multiple rows match the join condition then all the rows will be joined.

Comment: Yes, as @jarlh commented, it was because SQL Server couldn't verify the uniqueness of TableB (which in my case is a view with `union` statements). After adding `group by` for TableB it doesn't affect the execution plan if it's columns are not used